# copy_to_user set array at index

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, kernel, driver

I am writing a character device driver, but at the moment it freezes, and i have to reboot to stop it or crashes and the terminal exits
I have a global array

```
char* array;
```

On which i use `kmalloc(9, GFP_KERNEL)` so it should be the size of 9. If i wanted to use `file operations .write` to set a specific index how would i do that?
This is my current code (which crashes and terminal exits)

```
ssize_t mydriver_write(struct file *filp, const char* buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    raw_copy_to_user(array[*buf], 'x', 1);
}
```

EDIT:
I have already tried this version aswell

```
    raw_copy_to_user(&array[3], x, 1);
```

where `x` is kmalloc'd to size 1 and `x[0]='x'`
But in this case my program freezes and i cannot remove the driver and the machine requires a reboot to remove it.

Comment: I don't know these functions, but I imagine `raw_copy_to_user`'s second argument should be a pointer to a char. (If so, don't have you have compiler warnings enabled???) Also, you access `*buf` when `count` is `0`, which is probably not safe.

Comment: @ikegami i have added a version i've already tried in the question, but it also does not work

Comment: `raw_copy_to_user` makes a check to verify if the destination buffer is in user-space .... `kmalloc` allocates memory in kernel space

Comment: When implement `.write` file operation usage of `copy_to_user` and other functions from this family has a sense only for writing into the memory pointed by `buf`. Using `copy_to_user` for other purposes simply **wrong**.